# Change game speed in Stronghold with laptop keyboard without numpad

Tags: stronghold-kingdoms

I knew that in Strong hold game, we can change gamespeed by press +/- on the NumPad, but my laptop doesn't have the Numpad, how can i change the gamespeed in this game?

Comment: Try using the plus on the letters next to enter button i think and the hyphen ( - ) as a minus.